# Appcelerator. Break the chain of navigation

Tags: appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app and I need to know how to "break/clear" the chain of navigation so that I have full control over when the back button appears.

How can I break/clear this "chain"?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the back button by doing `Ti.UI.currentWindow.leftNavButton = null` assuming you are using the `Ti.UI.iPhone.NavigationGroup`.

This is how they do it in the [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/window_navbar.js#L176).

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that right now but I want to "clear" the stack so I do not have to hide the back button. Is this possible?

Comment: Not that I know of with Titanium, you could preload the windows when you create them with `leftNavButton: null` if you're worried about delayed animation?